# Display purchase_date for each product_id that exists in both stores

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to display for each product_id **that exists in both stores** the purchase_date for store A and store B **in two columns separately**, instead of showing it on a per-row basis.

Main_table

```
product_id   store  purchase_date
44343        A      2019-01-01
44343        B      2019-01-03
23234        A      2019-02-01
23234        B      2019-02-02
55433        A      2019-01-15
55433        B      2019-01-16
22324        A      2019-01-01
74456        B      2019-01-01
```

Output_table

```
product_id    purchase_date_storeA   purchase_date_storeB
44343              2019-01-01        2019-01-03
23234              2019-02-01        2019-02-02
55433              2019-01-15        2019-01-16
```

This is what I have tried so far, but with no success:

```
select 
purchase_date,
product_id,
case when store = 'A' then purchase_date end as purchase_date_storeA,
case when store = 'B.' then purchase_date end as purchase_date_storeB


from main_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
select 
product_id,
max(case when store = 'A' then purchase_date end) as purchase_date_storeA,
max(case when store = 'B' then purchase_date end) as purchase_date_storeB
from main_table
where store in ('A','B')
group by product_id
having count(distinct store) = 2
```